# Installing QGIS on Mac OS Sierra 10.12.5. "The GDAL 2.1 framework is required."

Tags: qgis, gdal, installation, mac

I use the version on web("http://www.kyngchaos.com/software/qgis").
Whether I come to install QGIS 2.18.9-1 or QGIS 2.14.15-1,  I click on the QuantumGIS.pkg and it opens the install dialogue box but with a warning "The GDAL 2.1 framework is required."

Could anyone give me a clue how to properly install QGIS on  Mac?
The version is Mac OS Sierra 10.12.5.

Comment: I can't also install QGIS. I installed the three others in order but when I try opening the QGIS package, the installation box won't open. I'm using macOS Sierra.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/122944)

Answer (score 3):

Have you read the Read Me.rtf file ?

> This distribution requires my GDAL Complete 2.1 framework package, and the Matplotlib and NumPy python modules.  These are included on the QGIS disk image.

[image]

The installation order is

1. GDAL Complete.pkg (GDAL 2.1 framework installed in `/Library/Frameworks/GDAL.framework`)
2. Numpy package (Python module installed in `/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages`)
3. matplotlib package (Python module  installed in `/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages`))
4. and finally the QGIS package (`Application /Applications/QGIS.app`)

Answer (score 0):

You can try [NextGIS QGIS](https://my.nextgis.com/downloads/software/installer/nextgis-setup.dmg) network installer. 
Some details about this QGIS build can be found here: http://nextgis.com/nextgis-qgis/

and here: http://nextgis.com/blog/qgis17/

[image]