# Error when starting QGIS 3

Tags: python, qgis-3

I get an error when starting QGIS 3.
Then I type this into python console:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

See response below.
What is the problem?

```
Python Console
Use iface to access QGIS API interface or Type help(iface) for more info
Security warning: typing commands from an untrusted source can lead to data loss and/or leak
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/code.py", line 91, in runcode
    exec(code, self.locals)
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Applications/QGIS3.app/Contents/MacOS/../Resources/python/qgis/utils.py", line 672, in _import
    mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'matplotlib'
```

Something wrong with the installation?
Should I uninstall, delete everything and re-intall?

Comment: Thanks MrXsquared for editing. Any way I can paste the syntax better  - like the way that you made it look ?

Comment: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/246187/installing-qgis-on-mac-os-sierra-10-12-5-the-gdal-2-1-framework-is-required - might do it.